# I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using the viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So I'm accessing some data (settings) from a .plist as my view appears. When I use the `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method to access that data everything works just fine and dandy. But when I access the data using the `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method to access my data everything stops and I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Can someone please help me out with this?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSLog(@"View Will Appear method");

    NSString *filePath = [self settingsFilePath];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        if ([[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue] == 0) {
            UIImage *imageLow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
            [object1 setImage:imageLow];
            [imageLow release];
            unitRatio = 1.8;
        }
        else if ([[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue] == 1) {
            UIImage *imageHigh = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
            [object1 setImage:imageHigh];
            [imageHigh release];
            unitRatio = 0.9;
        }

        [array release];

    }
    else {
        UIImage *imageLow = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
        [object1 setImage:imageLow];
        [imageLow release];
        unitRatio = 1.8;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you post the code for us? is this when the view appears for the first time? or only when you switch back to it?

Comment: when I switch back to it...I'm thinking it may have something to do with releasing objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[imageLow release]` and `[imageHigh release]` calls are unnecessary and will cause a crash. The objects returned by `imageNamed:` are pre-autoreleased, so you don't need to release them yourself.

Comment: Don't be so sure that the objects returned from `imageNamed:` are autoreleased. All you should care about is whether you own the returned object. If you do, you must release it when you're done. The method's name does not imply ownership, so there's no need to release. It is unnecessary and misleading to think about the implementation details such as whether it is already auto-released.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you must have a call to super in your viewWillAppear method:

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated]
```

That's not what is causing the crash, but the docs say it's required.